# KNN density estimation plot

Tags: r, plot, knn

I've tried looking around for on the internet (mainly google) but I was not able to find how to plot a density estimation of knn objects (within the 'class' package using the knn function).

Consider the example below (from the example in the help page).

```
require(class)

train <- as.data.frame(rbind(iris3[1:25,,1], iris3[1:25,,2], iris3[1:25,,3]))

test <- as.data.frame(rbind(iris3[26:50,,1], iris3[26:50,,2], iris3[26:50,,3]))

train$factor <- factor(c(rep("s",25), rep("c",25), rep("v",25)))

knn.results<-knn(train=train[,1:4], test=test[,1:4], cl=train$factor, k = 3)
```

What I would like is to have a plot that looks something like this (note, this was taken from this [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/21572/how-to-plot-decision-boundary-of-a-k-nearest-neighbor-classifier-from-elements-o)).

[image]

I'm a complete novice at R, but looking at the code, I think the knn function is only using 2 features. In my real data set (such as the one from the example) have more than 3 features. So my question is how would I show a plot with multiple features?

Let me know, thanks.

Comment: You can't produce a plot like that when you have 3 features. One of the reasons the book examples have only 2 features is that the feature space is just a plane, so the modelled response is a height above the plane. That lets you plot it using `contour` and the like.

Comment: Thanks for the response. One part of me thought thought like that. But other thought it was possible somehow.

In any case, if nobody has any objections, Hong's answer is correct.

Comment: use dimensionality reduction techniques like MDS, or PCA